# Does 'Clear Cookie' delete the cookie?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

There's a `Cookies` subsection under the `Resources` tab in DevTools... right clicking on any of the cookies gives me a `Clear` option. But is this the same as deleting the cookie, or will it just clear the contents? The UI does not remove the cookie from view, it just shows empty content.

Sometimes I  may check for the existence of a cookie instead of reading the data from it to verify, so this is a matter of consequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you call a cookie is actually a site. If you click on a site, you get a list of actual cookies for this site on the right side of the window with their name, contents, size etc... Each line is a cookie. You can delete individual cookies there.

When you clear a site, it deletes all the cookies from this site in one click, but as you can't delete a site, it still shows on the left side of the window.

Answer (score 1):

`Delete`/`Clear all` features remove cookies completely. You can test it quite easily yourself:

- open the Console
- type `document.cookies`
- remove a cookie using Resources tab
- type `document.cookies` again and compare the output with the previous one

You will find out that cookie you removed with Resources was removed completely.